# What are the options to design GUIs for Bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, user-interface, scripting

I have been doing a lot of scripting these days and was wondering if there would be some good solutions to this heart-rendering problem of designing smooth GUI's for Bash scripts. Any suggestion would be adored.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? What are the requirements for your GUI? Should it be run inside a terminal or desktop session? Does it need mouse support?

Comment: A desktop session would be good?